# Link a photo with the cell in excel

Tags: excel, cell, photo

Is there anyone who knows how to connect a picture with the cell that it is in at microsoft excel?

For example in the first column I put some brands of mobile phones and in the second one some pictures of them. Now when I sort the values of the first column alphabetically, I want the pictures of the second one to keep up…

How can I do that?

Answer (score 18):

There is a much simpler way. Put your picture in a comment box within the description cell. That way you only have one column and when you sort the picture will always stay with the description. Okay... Right click the cell containing the description... Insert comment...right click the outer border... Format comment...colours and lines tab... Colour drop down...Fill effects...Picture tab...select picture...browse for your picture (it might be best to keep all pictures in one folder for ease of placement)...ok... you will probably need to go to the size tab and frig around with the height and width.
Done... You now only need to mouse over the red in the top right corner of the cell and the picture will appear...like magic.

This method means that the row height can be kept to a minimum and the pictures can be as big as you like.

Comment: Pure genius @John!  Not just the best end result of any answer, but the simplest!

Answer (score 2):

Hold down the Alt key and drag the pictures to snap to the upper left corner of the cell.

Format the picture and in the Properties tab select "Move but don't size with cells"

Now you can sort the data table by any column and the pictures will stay with the respective data.

This post at SuperUser has a bit more background and screenshots: https://superuser.com/questions/712622/put-an-equation-object-in-an-excel-cell/712627#712627

Answer (score 1):

Select both the column you are sorting, and the column that the picture is in (I am assuming the picture is small compared to the cell, i.e. it is "in" the cell). Make sure that the object positioning property is set as "move but don't size with cells".
Now if you do a sort, the pictures will move with the list being sorted.

Note - you must include the column with the picture in your range when you sort, and the picture must fit inside the cell.

The following VBA snippet will make sure all pictures in your spreadsheet have their "move and size" property set:

```
Sub moveAndSize()
Dim s As Shape
For Each s In ActiveSheet.Shapes
  If s.Type = msoPicture Or s.Type = msoLinkedPicture Or s.Type = msoPlaceholder Then
    s.Placement = xlMove
  End If
Next
End Sub
```

If you want to make sure the picture continues to fit after you move it, you can use `xlMoveAndSize` instead of `xlMove`.